# Blocking problem Deserializing XML to object problem

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a blocking problem
I have XML file under some url

```
http://myserver/mywebApp/myXML.xml
```

In the below code which I run in Console Application, bookcollection has null Books field :(

```
<books>
<book id="5352">
<date>1986-05-05</date>
<title>
Alice in chains
</title>
 </book>
<book id="4334">
<date>1986-05-05</date>
<title>
1000 ways to heaven
</title>
 </book>
<book id="1111">
<date>1986-05-05</date>
<title>
Kitchen and me
</title>
 </book>
</books>
```

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); 
doc.Load("http://myserver/mywebapp/myXML.xml");
BookCollection books = new BookCollection();

XmlNodeReader reader2 = new XmlNodeReader(doc.DocumentElement);
XmlSerializer ser2 = new XmlSerializer(books.GetType());
object obj = ser2.Deserialize(reader2);

BookCollection books2=   (BookCollection)obj; 



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    [Serializable()]
      public class Book
        {
             [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("id")]
            public string id { get; set; }

             [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("date")]
            public string date { get; set; }

              [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("title")]
            public string title { get; set; }


        }
}





using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    [Serializable()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("books", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public class BookCollection
    {
        [XmlArray("books")]
        [XmlArrayItem("book", typeof(Book))]
        public Book[] Books { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't duplicate tags like "C#, .NET" in the title. Leave them in the tags. That's what the tags are for! Also, to format code and/or XML, select them in the editor and press Control-K.

Answer (score 1):

That appears to expect `/books/books/book`. Try instead:

```
    [XmlElement("book")]
    public Book[] Books { get; set; }
```

(no array/array-item)

Answer (score 1):

Marc is 100% correct, by changing the attribute you use on the Books array you can correctly deserialize the XML. One thing I also want to point out is when you construct your XmlSerializer like this

```
BookCollection books = new (); 
XmlSerializer ser2 = new XmlSerializer(books.GetType());
```

It is not neccesary to new an instance of BookCollection to get the type. You should rather be using `typeof`

```
XmlSerializer ser2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BookCollection));
```

And as per Marc's point the complete BookCollection class should look like this

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("books", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]  
public class BookCollection  
{  
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("book")]  
    public Book[] Books { get; set; }  
}
```

Putting the `XmlElement` attribute on an `Array` or any of the serializeable collections like `List` and `List<T>` basically tells the serializer you want the elements of the array serialized as child elements of the current element ie. since you are providing the  element via the `BooksCollection` class you just want the array serialized as child elements of the `BooksCollection`.